# Lower bound for the number of edges in a Minkowski sum

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, polytopes

I was wondering whether the following statement about a Minkowski sum of two polytopes is true:

Let $P=P_1 + P_2$ be the Minkowski sum of two polytopes $P_1$ and $P_2$ in $\Bbb R^n$, i.e. $P=\{p_1+p_2: p_1\in P_1, p_2 \in P_2\}$. Then the number of edges (1-dim. faces) of $P$ is at least the maximum of the number of edges of $P_1$ and $P_2$, i.e. if $f_1(P)$ denotes the number of edges of $P$, then $f_1(P) \geq \max\{f_1(P_1),f_1(P_2)\}$. For my purposes, one may assume that the origin lies in the interior of $P_1$ and $P_2$.

Can someone please provide a reference, proof, or counterexample? (Or state if it's unknown). Thank you in advance.

As a follow-up question: does $P$ have more vertices than $P_1$ and $P_2$? What about facets, or more generally, $k$-faces?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to consider the extremal case of 2 mutually perpendicular polytopes $P$ and $Q$. There the Minkowski sum then simply is just

$$(P,0) + (0,Q) = P \times Q$$

the according Cartesian product or duoprism. For that one you clearly would have

$$f_1(P \times Q) = f_0(P) f_1(Q) + f_1(P) f_0(Q)$$

Next you would have to consider quite generally (any relation of $P$ and $Q$) that $P+Q$ is describable as some projection or shadow of $P \times Q$.

--- rk

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you please explain why the Cartesian product is the extremal case?

Comment: Extremal in the sense that $P$ and $Q$ live in complementary spaces, and that esp. all edges of $P \times Q$ remain externally visible.

Comment: Thank you for your follow-up comment. Perhaps I am missing something, but if all edges remain externally visible under the sum, then isn't one maximizing the number of edges the sum can have rather than minimizing it? Intuitively it seems that the extremal case for a lower bound is when P and Q are homothetic.

Comment: Yes for both. Esp. as in the latter case the homothety ensures that corresponding edges are parallel and therefore those would merge into a single one in the Minkowski sum.

Comment: Thank you again for your response. It is unclear to me then what your argument is - why would you consider $P\times Q$ if you are trying to establish a lower bound, not an upper bound? After reading more about this, it seems the inequality holds as a consequence of the fact that the normal fan of the sum of polytopes is the common refinement of the fans, no? (and thus the inequality holds for all $k$-faces?)

Comment: The Minkowski sum is not too clear visualizable. In the Cartesian product everything behaves within either of those perpendicular spaces. It is much clearer. Thus having understood those shapes of duoprisms, it is much easier to iron those perpendicular spaces down into a common space, i.e. applying some projection which yields some shadow thereof. As a matter of fact some k-facets thereby remain visible, others not. - I just wanted to hint you onto that relation to the Cartesian product.